# Generate huge xml from java objects with camel

Tags: java, jaxb, apache-camel, stax

I try to generate a huge xml with Camel from java objects (from a database).

Is there a way to do this with a camel route, loading data from database to objects, marshalling them to xml and streaming to a file, in order to minimize memory usage ?

I found many examples to split a huge xml file and insert data to database, but not the contrary.

The xml file to generate is similar to this :

```xml
<root>
  <libraryHeader>
    <field></field>
    <field></field>
    ...
  </libraryHeader>
  <books>
    <book>... <field></field> ...</book>
    <book>... <field></field> ...</book>
    ... 
  </books>
</root>

Thank you very much for your advices
```

Comment: Have you looked at [camel-stream](https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/stream-component.html)? It has option to stream to file which could work for your use case.

Comment: As for databases theres `camel-jdbc`, `camel-sql`, `camel-jpa` and many others. For marshalling/unmarshalling xml you could check out [JacksonXML](https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/dataformats/jacksonxml-dataformat.html)